# Controll the dc motor that works with 2xAA bateries using 5v

Tags: motor, electronics, voltage

I have a toy that has a dc motor and is runing with 2xAA bateries ( i think it is 3v motor)

So i want to run it with 5v power supply.

First question: Can 5v damage the motor

Second question: i think i need to add diode but dont know what diode to add and how to determine what i need

Third question: is there a combination that i can add series of diode so i can drop voltage to 3v

Comment: 1) yes ... 2) research motor control with arduino ... 3) yes

Comment: `can drop current tl 3v` ...  current is not measured in volts ... it is measured in amps

Answer (score 0):

[DC electric motors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_motor) are usually rated to run over a range of voltages.  If you are unsure of the specifications of the DC electric motors you have, consider buying new motors which are specified to operate in a rage that includes 5VDC.

Consider not running both the processor (Arduino) and any high current demanding device off the same power source.  Such as solenoids or motors.  This is especially true for mobile devices supplied by battery voltage.  Often is the case the processor will reset (behave unexpectedly) should the supply voltage drop because of activating a solenoid or motor.

Diodes and other components are added to suppress or mitigate undesired effects of a solenoid or motor.  Inductive loads such as solenoids or motors resist changes in current flow and can damage connected components if the undesired current flow is beyond the connected component's abilities.  Read [this stackexchange question/answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/95140/purpose-of-the-diode-and-capacitor-in-this-motor-circuit) for more about this.

A silicon diode has a forward bias voltage drop of about 0.6 volts.  Other diodes have different forward bias voltage drops.  [This wikipedia article lists a few different diodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Forward_threshold_voltage_for_various_semiconductors). It may be possible to arrange enough diodes in series to drop 5 volts to 3 volts.

Consider searching for a 5VDC controllable Arduino relay module.  There are plenty on the web.  Such a device should include the circuitry to safely control the relay and the relay should provide more than adequate isolation from the DC motor.

For a learning experience, consider following [this Arduino / Motor tutorial provided by Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-13-dc-motors).